# '...' is not a postfix unary operator - Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift3, operators

I just want to remove one part of string .

```
if let dotRange = detailArticleContent?.range(of: "<iframe") {

    detailArticleContent.removeSubrange( dotRange.lowerBound... < detailArticleContent.endIndex )
    //In this line i got err : '...' is not a postfix unary operator 

   }
```

Comment: why did you even put this operator then? with < operator just separated? what range you want to do?

Comment: I want to half parts of string like this detailArticleContent = detailArticleContent.componentsSeparatedByString("<iframe")[0]  But i also got err : Value of type 'String?' has no member 'componentsSeparatedByString'

Comment: because it is optional string, you need to check if there is anything after separating

Comment: I track values in debugger but i will double check for sure

Comment: not track in debugger, check in code to let know compiler that everything is ok and components separated will be available

Comment: I fixed this job with :  detailArticleContent = detailArticleContent?.components(separatedBy : "<iframe")[0]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151605/discussion-between-nikola-lukic-and-lu).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use either `...` (close range) or `..<` (half close range, before last), there's nothing like `... <`

Answer (score 7):

In my case i given space between **0..<** and **dictionary.count**

Correct one is :

```
0..<dictionary.count

//Wrong 
let dictionary = dic["predictions"] as! [String:Any]
    print(dictionary)
    for index in 0..< dictionary.count {
        print(<#T##items: Any...##Any#>)
    }

//Correct 
let dictionary = dic["predictions"] as! [String:Any]
    print(dictionary)
    for index in 0..<dictionary.count {
        print(<#T##items: Any...##Any#>)
    }
```